# angular ui-router stuck in between states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using UI-Router in a project. I am using the state resolve functionality provided by the router. When I want to display a loader in between two states and I change states very often the spinner pops up but don't disappear anymore. 
The same effect can be found here. 
http://rp.js.org/angular-ui-view-spinner/example/index.html 
If one clicks fast between the two states the loader won't hide. 
I am waiting for the stateChangeStart broadcast and display the loader and on statChangeSuccess, stateChangeError and viewContentLoaded I want't to hide the loader. The stateChangeStart gets fired but stateChangeSuccess doesn't. Any idea why this behaviour appears? 
I am using angular-ui-router in version 0.2.18

Here the Code for show and hide:

```
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', showLoading);
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', hideLoading);
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', hideLoading);
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', hideLoading);

    function showLoading() {
        $timeout(function () {
            angular.element('.loading-indicator').show();
        }, 50);
    }


    function hideLoading() {
        $timeout(function () {
            angular.element('.loading-indicator').hide();
        }, 50);
    }
```

Comment: Out of interest why are you showing a loading animation are you making some sort of ajax request?

Comment: Yes exactly. I am fetching backend resources in the resolver function of the state and go to the state afterwards. But i am not sure if the promise will be resolved after a second or a minute. To give the user the feeling that something happens, I display a loader above the content area but not above the navigation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel previous timer. See documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout.

```
var yourTimer;
function showLoading() {
    if (yourTimer) {$timeout.cancel(yourTimer);}
    yourTimer = $timeout(function () {
        angular.element('.loading-indicator').show();
    }, 50);
}


function hideLoading() {
    if (yourTimer) {$timeout.cancel(yourTimer);}
    yourTimer = $timeout(function () {
        angular.element('.loading-indicator').hide();
    }, 50);
}
```

Comment: Hey niels thank you for the fast reply. I am currently on vacation but i ll let you know if it worked. Would be so great.

Comment: I am sorry that it took me forever to check if your answer works and give a reply. So I added your lines to cancel the timeout if a timer exists, but the spinner still keeps spinning when changing states too fast.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand for which reason you use a timer for loading spinner, i recommend use only css if you use for the animation.

Here a little of my code:
HTML

```
<div ui-view class="fade container-fluid"></div>
<div class="spinner modal-viewer" hidden>
    <div class="transparente"></div>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <div class="center-middle">
            <div class="sk-circle">
                <div class="sk-circle1 sk-child"></div>
                <div class="sk-circle2 sk-child"></div>
                ...
                <div class="sk-circle11 sk-child"></div>
                <div class="sk-circle12 sk-child"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You need manage them out of the uiView, because when you let out of a state, you will lose control of the state controller, then you can't disappear the spinner.
For that, put the spinner out of the uiView element, as above example.

JS

```
document.querySelector('.spinner')['style'].display = 'none';
```

My apologies for my poor previous answer.